# Problems while connecting to WebDav using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, webdav

I have never used WebDav before but recently my client asked me to upload some files to his server. This proccess should be automated so I decided to use python to do this

My client has given me the info about the server in the following format:

> Server location: \123.456.789.012\Something
>
> Username: user
>
> Password: pass
>
> Domain: somedomain

I am trying to use `easywebdav` framework to do the job, however I get the following results:
Code:

```
webdav = easywebdav.connect(
    host='123.456.789.012/Something',
    username='user',
    port=80,
    protocol="http",
    password='pass'
)

print(webdav.ls())
```

And the the exception I get is

> Operation     :  PROPFIND .
>
> Expected code :  207 Multi-Status, 301 Moved Permanently
>
> Actual code   :  401 Unauthorized

I might not be understanding everything correctly since I already tried multiple frameworks and they all fail the same way, but I HAVE successfully connected to the server using the same credentials via MAC OS X webdav client built-in Finder so it does work correctly.

I am sorry for the format of the question and probably lack of details, I am currently desperate after several hours trying to fix this problem. Feel free to ask anything in comments!

Comment: Hello, can you try `webdav = easywebdav.connect(
    host='123.456.789.012',
    username='user',
    port=80,
    protocol="http",
    password='pass', path='/something'
)`?

Comment: @piotr-dawidiuk Well we have some progress. For `webdav.ls()` which is `webdav.ls(".")` I get error 500, for `webdav.ls("/Something")` error 401 again.  Any Ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: 500 was a single issue, it seems. Now I get 401 for any path.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem. After using Wireshark to find out how my OS X(WebdavFS) connects I found out that the server is Microsoft IIS 7.5 and requires NTLM Auth instead of Basic Auth. Haven't found any python libraries that support NTLM Auth so luckily due to the fact the app is relatively small I swithed to C++ using [neon library](http://webdav.org/neon/).